# OPGFeedbackSDK: How to authenticate using OnePoint SDK for mobile surveys?

Tags: ios, sdk, cocoapods

I am trying to install OnePoint Global OPGFeedbackSDK as Cocoa Pods. After successful installation of pod, I am unable to authenticate and take a sample survey. Please help.

Comment: There is the code `OPGSDK.initialize(withUserName: "SDK_Username", withSDKKey: "SDK_SharedKey")` on the sample example https://github.com/OnePointGlobal/OPGFeedbackSDK/blob/master/Example/OPGFeedbackSDK/AppDelegate.swift Do you have a Key?